# Self-defined plugin cannot infer by QuerySpec Constructor

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I try to upgrade my self-defined plugin from ES5.5 to ES6.3.
In ES5.5 my own plugin works well. But in ES6.3, QuerySpec constructor cannot infer it.
Here are the Code Snippets in ES6.3:

1. **AbstractVectorQuery**

```
public abstract class AbstractVectorQuery extends Query
{
    protected String field;
    protected float[] qVector;
    protected VectorFieldType vectorFieldType;
    protected DistanceMeasure distHelper;

    protected AbstractVectorQuery(String field, float[] qVector, DistanceMeasure distHelper, VectorFieldType fieldType)
    {
        this.field = field;
        this.qVector = qVector;
        this.distHelper = distHelper;
        this.vectorFieldType = fieldType;
    }
}
```

2. **VectorIterQuery**

```
public class VectorIterQuery extends AbstractVectorQuery
{
    public VectorIterQuery(String field, float[] vector, DistanceMeasure distHelper, VectorFieldType vectorFieldType)
    {
        super(field, vector, distHelper, vectorFieldType);
    }
}
```

3. **DistanceVectorQueryBuilder**

```
public abstract class DistanceVectorQueryBuilder<T extends DistanceVectorQueryBuilder<T>>
    extends AbstractVectorQueryBuilder<T>
{
    public static final DistanceType DEFAULT_DISTANCE_TYPE = DistanceType.L2;
    protected DistanceType distanceType = DEFAULT_DISTANCE_TYPE;

    protected abstract void innerInnerDoXContent(XContentBuilder builder, Params params) throws IOException;

    protected DistanceVectorQueryBuilder(){}

    protected DistanceVectorQueryBuilder(StreamInput in) throws IOException
    {
        super(in);
        this.distanceType = in.readEnum(DistanceType.class);
    }
}
```

4. **IterVectorQueryBuilder**

```
public class IterVectorQueryBuilder extends DistanceVectorQueryBuilder<IterVectorQueryBuilder>
{
    public static final String QUERY_NAME = "iter";

    public IterVectorQueryBuilder(StreamInput input) throws IOException
    {
        super(input);
    }
}
```

5. **VectorPlugin**
   Here, IDE reports:
   *Cannot infer arguments (unable to resolve constructor)*

```
public class VectorPlugin extends Plugin implements MapperPlugin, SearchPlugin
{
    @Override
    public List<QuerySpec<?>> getQueries()
    {
        List<QuerySpec<?>> list = new ArrayList<>();

        QuerySpec<IterVectorQueryBuilder> iterQuery = new QuerySpec<>(
                IterVectorQueryBuilder.QUERY_NAME,
                IterVectorQueryBuilder::new,
                IterVectorQueryBuilder::fromXContent
        );
        list.add(iterQuery);
    }
}
```

Any suggetions will really appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, actually the problem didn't exist in code snippet I posted, sorry for the misunderstand.

Change return type of IterVectorQueryBuilder::fromXContent
from

```
Optional<IterVectorQueryBuilder> fromXContent(QueryParseContext parseContext) throws IOException { ... }
```

to

```
IterVectorQueryBuilder fromXContent(QueryParseContext parseContext) throws IOException { ... }
```

would solve this problem.